# Using rails, devise and cancan, a signed in user can access the sign in and sign up paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-routing

I'm not sure what I did, but a signed in user can access the new_user_session_path and     new_user_registration_path. Usually in devise, a user should not be allowed to access those paths. I'm using cancan if the makes a difference. I created a new rails application and copied over the routes and extended the registrations and sessions controller and cannot replicate the problem.

If someone could even point me in the direction of where the redirecting is done in Devise, I would appreciate it.

In the initializers/devise.rb config file, the only line added to the default file is:

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

Let me know if I can supply any other useful information.
I'm using Devise (1.5.3), CanCan (1.6.7), and Rails (3.1.1)

Routes File:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions", :registrations => "registrations" }, :skip => [ :sessions, :registations ] do

    get    '/signin'   => 'sessions#new',     :as => :new_user_session
    post   '/signin'   => 'sessions#create',  :as => :user_session
    delete '/signout'  => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session

    get    '/signup'       => 'registrations#new',    :as => :new_user_registration
    post   '/users'        => 'registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
    get    '/users/cancel' => 'registrations#cancel', :as => :cancel_user_registration
    get    '/settings'     => 'registrations#edit',   :as => :edit_user_registration

    put    '/account'      => 'registrations#update'
    delete '/users'        => 'registrations#destroy'
  end

  resources :users

  match '/contact',   :to => 'pages#contact'

  root :to => 'pages#contact'

end
```

Extended Devise Registrations Controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource

    resource.company = Company.find_by_code(params[:company_code])
    resource.role = Role.find_by_name("Basic")

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :inactive_signed_up, :reason => inactive_reason(resource) if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

end
```

Extended Devise Sessions Controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout "sessions"
end
```

I realize that I can add some code to the controller actions or in a before filter to check for a logged in user and redirect them. Devise, however, offers the functionality and I shouldn't have to do that. I'm afraid that by doing so I may be ignoring a larger problem, perhaps with Devise's configuration.

I appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: "Devise, however, offers the functionality" how do you know that? Where does it say?

Comment: I've asked several people who use it as well as started a fresh rails app and installed devise. Devise won't let you navigate to the sign in or sign up pages after logging in. I can't even seem to break the functionality in order to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and trying, I decided to re-implement devise and it did the trick. I'm still not sure how I managed to break the functionality in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

For devise 1.5.3; not really an answer but some pointers as to what's going on under the hood.
The filter that is used to redirect when user is signed in is [require_no_authentication](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/442beefa9b1f7d4623ded34278dc91a9d69dab24/lib/devise/controllers/internal_helpers.rb#L93).
It is already called in devises's [sessions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/59cd9e72b9cb2ffc98d41b1bbad04c7849a97a2e/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L2) and [registrations](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/59cd9e72b9cb2ffc98d41b1bbad04c7849a97a2e/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L2) controllers.
Since you extend these controllers and filters are inherited, you should have the behavior applied.

Some possible actions:

- add breakpoints to see if the filter is called or not
- introspect the controllers in console to see if filters get registered
- check the filter's control flow; have you tinkered with `Devise.navigational_formats`
- double check devise version

Comment: Thank you clyfe. I'm having the same trouble (able to access 'users/sign_in') when I delete my sessions controller and remove the routes. I'm now using devise 1.8.11 with the same issue.